# Checkbox selected within hidden div

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox, checkboxlist

I have a C# Checkboxlist within a hidden div.  The div displays upon certain events, then is closed.  When the form is submitted, I try to update database bit fields based on selected values of the checkboxlist.items but they always return false whether checked or not.  How can I get the selected value of the items when the div containing them is hidden?

The div is a dialog I show/hide using jquery

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#<%=txtLANG.ClientID %>').click(function () {
            $("#overlay-back").dialog({
                resizable: false,
                modal: true,
                width: 500,
                height: 400,
                buttons: {
                    OK: function () {
                        GetLanguages();
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    },
                    Cancel: function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

and here's the DIV...the codebehind is nothing more than setting a parameter to true/false based on selected value of the checkboxlist items

```
<div id="overlay-back" style="display:none;">
        <table width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td width="50%">
                    <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkEnglish" TextAlign="Right" Text=" English" />
                    <div class="popup-container">
                            <img id="help_button_chkEnglish" class="help-button" src="/Images/help-button.png" alt="" />
                                <div class="help-popup hidden" id="help_popup_chkEnglish">
                                    <div class="popup-arrow-border"></div> <div class="popup-arrow"></div>
                                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblLANGDesc"></asp:Label>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                </td>
                <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlTopLanguages">
                <td rowspan="3" valign="top">
                    <asp:CheckBoxList ID="chkTopLanguages" TextAlign="Right" runat="server" />
                        <br />
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblNonTopLanguages"></asp:Label><br />
                    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtOtherLanguages" onkeypress="CopyOtherLangs(event)" onclick="clearLanguageSearchText()" Text="Other Languages..."></asp:TextBox>
                    <cc3:AutoCompleteExtender ID="aceSearch" runat="server" MinimumPrefixLength="1" TargetControlID="txtOtherLanguages"
                                                ServicePath="~/controls/wsCommunity.asmx" ServiceMethod="GetLanguageCompletionList">
                                        </cc3:AutoCompleteExtender>
                </td>
                <td rowspan="3">
                <div class="popup-container">
                            <img id="help_button_chkTopLanguages" class="help-button" src="/Images/help-button.png" alt="" />
                                <div class="help-popup hidden" id="help_popup_chkTopLanguages">
                                    <div class="popup-arrow-border"></div> <div class="popup-arrow"></div>
                                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblTopLangs"></asp:Label>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                </td>
                </asp:Panel>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkFrench" TextAlign="Right" Text=" French" />
                    <div class="popup-container">
                            <img id="help_button_chkFrench" class="help-button" src="/Images/help-button.png" alt="" />
                                <div class="help-popup hidden" id="help_popup_chkFrench">
                                    <div class="popup-arrow-border"></div> <div class="popup-arrow"></div>
                                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label2"></asp:Label>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlEnhancedFrench">
            <tr>
                <td valign="top">
                    <asp:CheckBoxList ID="chkEnhancedFrench" TextAlign="Right" CssClass="EnhancedFrench" runat="server">
                        <asp:ListItem> Customer Service</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem> Publications</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem> Website</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem> Interpreters</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:CheckBoxList>
                </td>
            </tr>
            </asp:Panel>
        </table>
        </div>
```

Comment: can you post the code for the div content and checkboxlist

Comment: Is it hidden via display:none or with .Visable = false in codebehind?

Comment: agree with Andrew Walters, make sure it is visible=false. because display: none entirely removes the element from the page, and the flow of the page is calculated as though the element were not there at all. On the other hand, visibility: hidden leaves the space in the document flow even though you can no longer see the element.

Comment: Are you re-binding it on postback possibly?

Comment: nope.  I think it's what you said before.  I have it set to display:none;  but is there another way to do it via jquery?  I'm not thinking so but unsure